# Reference to a Two-Dimesional Array

Tags: c++

I want to implement a function with OpenGL to render a cylinder in C++. The signature of my function is as follows:

```
#define POINTS_NUM  15
#define DEMESION    3
    
void drawCylinder( int slices, int segments, GLfloat (&vertices)[ POINTS_NUM ][ DEMESION ] );
```

I want to use a reference to a two-dimensional array to limit user input, but some strange behavior is happening. When I implement the function declared as above, an linker error occurs:

> Error 1 error LNK2005: "float (* vase)[3]" (?vase@@3PAY02MA) already defined in shapes.obj vase.obj VaseAndAnimation

Here `vase` is defined as:

```
GLfloat vase[ POINTS_NUM ][ DEMESION ];
```

At first, I thought there was something wrong with the last dimension. So I omitted it in my second trial. This time declaration of my function is like this:

```
void drawCylinder( int slices, int segments, GLfloat (&vertices)[ POINTS_NUM ][] );
```

Now a compile-time error occurs when invoked as (`vase` definition isn't changed):

```
drawCylinder( 10, 10, vase );
```

Compile error:

> Error 1 error C2087: 'vertices' : missing subscript d:\visual studio 2008\projects\project1\computer graphics\vaseandanimation\shapes.h 25 VaseAndAnimation
>
> Error 2 error C2664: 'drawCylinder' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'GLfloat [14][3]' to 'GLfloat (&)[14][1]' d:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\Computer Graphics\VaseAndAnimation\vase.cpp 64 VaseAndAnimation
>
> Error 3 error C2087: 'vertices' : missing subscript d:\visual studio 2008\projects\project1\computer graphics\vaseandanimation\shapes.h 25 VaseAndAnimation
>
> Error 4 error C2087: 'vertices' : missing subscript d:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\Computer Graphics\VaseAndAnimation\shapes.cpp 12 VaseAndAnimation

From this error, I can see that parameter `vertices` is really treated a reference to a two-dimensional array, but why is `vase` parsed as `float (* vase)[3]` in my first version?

My IDE is Visual Studio 2008. I haven't tried it with GCC; is that behavior compiler-dependent?

Hope someone can give me a hand to get rid of the trap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a reference to a two-dimensional array to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404232/how-do-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first declaration is fine. Seems to be you have defined `vase` in a header file.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After carefully check my code, I find the vase is defined just before the function declaration. But why I can't define the array in header file? I didn't know any limit about that. Thanks.

Comment: Your header is included in several cpp files. This means that `vase` will be defined several times. You can declare it in a header and then defined it in one of cpp files.

Comment: Yes, I know this case. But, I've defined a macro to avoid duplicate included. There's still the problem.

Comment: Macro doesn't do the job in this case. You'll get one `vase` per cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is just that `vase` is being *defined* in a header file. You should only *declare* variables in header files.

This causes a problem because the multiple definitions produce multiple of the same symbol, which confuses the linker (hence the linker error). When the linker tries to match up references to the variable to the actual definition, it doesn't know which one to use.

Header guards don't protect against this. The macros used in a header guard are only defined *per translation unit*. Every time your compiler starts to compile a new .cpp file (ignoring unity builds etc.), that's a new translation unit and essentially the compiler is starting from scratch, not knowing about any symbols that have been previously defined.

To fix this, only *declare* your variables in header files:

```
// extern specifies that the definition is elsewhere.
extern int myGlobalVariable;
```

and then *define* that variable in **one** source file.

```
int myGlobalVariable;
```